# What is difference between metrics=accuracy and precision from confusion matrix?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

What is difference between metrics=accuracy and precision from each class that obtained from confusion matrix?

Is that any relationship between accuracy and precision?

How can i calculate loss from precision of each class? for example if precision from class 1 was 0.95, my loss is 0.05?

Comment: If you search in your browser for "accuracy prediction loss", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is difference between metrics=accuracy and precision from each
>   class that obtained from confusion matrix?

Accuracy = (Correct predictions)/(Total number of cases)

Precision = (True positive)/(Total number of positive predictions)

> How can i calculate loss from precision of each class?

Loss has to be calculated from the loss function defined for your network like `binary_crossentropy`.

Answer (score 0):

**Accuracy**: Is fraction of correct predictions in all prediction made by model. i.e. 
`no. of correct predictions / no. of total predictions`

**Precision**: Is fraction of correct positive predictions in all positive predictions made by the model i.e

`no. of correct positives/ no. of total positive predictions`

which is also equal to

`no. of correct positives/ (no. of correct positives + no. of wrong positives)`

There is also a third metric you want to consider

**Recall**: Is fraction of correct positive predictions made in actual positive data i.e

`correct positive predictions/actual positives`

If your data are balanced, i.e. have nearly same number of instance in each class then you can use accuracy, else you can use precision or accuracy based on either classifying instance in positive class or negative class is more important

There is not direct relation between loss and precision or any of above parameters because these parameters are calculated based on predictions but loss are calculated with probability of prediction for each class. When we make prediction based on probability we choose class with highest probability in doing so we lost information about it so we can't go back from prediction to probability.

Comment: Hi, So thanks. when i use metric= accuracy, i have a loss. but when i use confusion matrix, i have precision. i need to know how can i calculate loss from precision that obtained from confusion matrix.